# OpenGL z axis depth best practices

Tags: opengl-es

I'm working on 2D paint library. It uses OpenGL ES with orthographic projection. And I use z axis just to sort the order of visible elements. 
Now. I have some object in VBO (*object1*). All items in VBO have integer z value : 1,2,3,4,.... 
And I make another object (*object2*). Lets say I draw 2 lines:

```
Line1    z=1
Line2    z=2
```

And now I want to draw here my VBO(*object1*), so I left a little space for *object1*, lets say 1. And I proceed with filling lines, so at the end I have:

```
Line1    z=1
Line2    z=2
Line3    z=4   (here we give some space for object1)
Line4    z=5
```

When it comes time to draw, I draw object2 with

> mat2.scaleZ = 1/object2.lastZ

And object1 with:

```
 mat1.scaleZ  = 1/object1.lastZ
 mat1.offsetZ = 3

 mat1 = mat1*mat2   (apply object2 scale)
```

I draw object1 VBO with mat1, and object2 VBO with mat2 (that's why I need z-ordering).
At the end we'll have following z ordering (in OpenGL, after all matrices applied to vertices in vs ):

```
object2.Line1           0.1
object2.Line2           0.2
  object1.Line1         0.22        << problem here!
  object1.Line2         0.24
  object1.Line3         0.26
  object1.Line4         0.28
object2.Line3           0.3
object2.Line4           0.4
object2.Line5           0.5
object2.Line6           0.6
object2.Line7           0.7
object2.Line8           0.8
object2.Line9           0.9
object2.Line10          1.0
```

As you can see, object1's z band shrinks in 10 times (number of elements in object2).
And this is my problem. If I'll have 1000 elements in object2 and 1000 in object1 - I'll be realy close to float facilities. And if I'll want than some object3, which include object2 ... My z axis will float :)

The first thing comes to my mind - leave space = object1.lastZ. It will work, but if object1 will grow - I have to shrink it with matrix again (And maybe get the same issue).
 
The second thing - divide object2 in 2 VBO's. But that's not good, because I may want to insert object1 much often - and then I'll get a bulk of VBO's from object2, what is not an option.

Can someone advise me with this? Maybe I should take another approach?

P.S. Maybe I just mistaken about float precision in aprox. 7 numbers after dot?

Comment: Why do you use the z-test for order at all? You can draw the elements in order without depth test and will get the correct results.

Comment: Without depth test - I draw object1, than object2. And object2 will overlap object1, instead of be inside of it. As you see I left some space for object1 in object2

Comment: Well. you said "And I use z axis just to sort the order of visible elements.". So drawing in the correct order is enough. As you always use a distinct z value for each object, andall your objects are parallel to the xy plane, no issues with intersections can arise.

Comment: ok - how it should sounds? I'll corect my question:)

Comment: well, I don't know. I think your woriding is correct. But than the depth test is not strictly required (but could be used for sppedup).

Comment: " But than the depth test is not strictly required" - Why? How I can avoid using it?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43936/discussion-between-derhass-and-tower120)

Comment: Using a non-linear mapping from integer z to depth value will increase precision by a large amount. But actually I think @derhass approach will suit you better

Comment: @user1781290 - What is "non-linear mapping"?

Comment: Due to the way how floats work, smaller numbers are stored with higher accuracy. You can exploit this by using a logarithmic distribution (you can google for it). So you basically map as many values into 0..1 as you map into 1..10

Comment: @tower120: glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST) switched off depth testing. Things are drawn in order as you make the drawing calls and things drawn later will overlap everything drawn before.

Comment: @datenwolf "I draw object1 VBO with mat1, and object2 VBO with mat2 (that's why I need z-ordering)." If I'll disable it one object may completly overlap another.

Comment: 32-bit floating point type can hold millions of unique values. If you use something like a hashing algorithm you can utilize all of them.

Comment: @Bartek Banachewicz - what do you mean? how I should hash/unhash them? And I can rely only on 16bit ES float